# How to press a key of a peripheral device (not keyboard) from terminal/python?

Tags: python, usb, devices, sensors

I have recently acquired a dial indicator and a keyboard like device that when attached to the dial indicator it types the value of the dial indicator on the computer. It is similar to a keyboard. Here is the store page of the device with more information: https://shop.mitutoyo.eu/web/mitutoyo/en/mitutoyo/01.01.02/USB%20Input%20Tool/index.xhtml

What I am trying to achieve is that instead of my physically pressing the button on this device, I want to write a software that automatically presses the button to get the data every X seconds.

The device is in /dev/input and numbered "event14", I have managed to read the data when I physically press the button. But I could not figure how to let the software digitally presses it and retrieve the information.

Any help or resources are appreciated.

Comment: I think the manufacturer of the device should be able to answer this question. Pressing the button is probybly not the same as pressing a key on a keyboard. This may start some processing to retrieve the data and send it like keyboard input.  If the manufacturer did not provide a way to control the device's function by software, it might be necessary to electrically connect some software controllable switch to the button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work with the device that you have linked or not, but take a look at [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html).

> *"xdotool lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc."*

Here's example usage (create an empty file and write the following simple bash script inside):

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool key alt+shift+F12
```

Save the file as '.sh' and make it executable.

Do note that you need to be running X11 for this to work (it won't work on headless systems).